# Entity Exception Message At least one of the input paths is not valid because either it is too long or it has incorrect format

Tags: exception, entity-framework-4, entity

using EF4
I atempt to make a connection but get this error message 
**"Entity Exception  Message At least one of the input paths is not valid because either it is too long or it has incorrect format."**

This used the example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738533.aspx but passing in my own server name. What is the "input paths" 
When I run it from a web app its fine, when I try and run it in a unit/integration test passing in the connection (as app.config might not be there) I get this error.

Whats going on?

Comment: You need to show what you pass. Also the stack trace could be helpful too.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. I was writing the code in the following way

```
 ebuilder.Metadata = @"Model1.csdl, Model1.ssdl,Model1.msl";
```

Then after some research I changes it to

```
 ebuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl";
```

The magic happened and it started working.

Comment: Thanks, will give that a bash :)

Comment: Seems that you can now use a traditional connection string ADO style.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error in EF6. when I try to fetch something from DB, this error was thrown.
I solved this problem with correcting the MetaData part of my connectinString.
you must have MetaData part like below:
metadata=res://*/myModel.csdl|res://*/myModel.ssdl|res://*/myModel.msl;